# Xcode: Memory Usage Comparison

Tags: xcode

[image]

Is it normal to lose 3/4 of memory to 'Other Processes' when simulating iOS in xcode?

Comment: Thank very much for the down vote. You're input to my question was very useful, and your advice will clearly not only benefit me, but also the stack exchange community, of which you feel superior enough to not even to type a few key strokes to identify where i could improve on this. Thanks again

Comment: I think the question is relevant, so I upvoted you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.

"Other Processes" includes literally every other program that is currently running on your Mac. That number has nothing to do with the simulator. It does not measure processes that run in the simulator.

If you run iOS Simulator Xcode shows memory stats from your Mac.